# Adding gradient to UIView is causing an error

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I'm using RubyMotion. The error message I see in Terminal is:

> rake aborted! Command failed with status (1):
>   [DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.a...]
>   /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project.rb:101:in `block in <top
>   (required)>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`
>   eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => default => simulator

So the error is occurring in a file created by RubyMotion itself, not one of my files. Obviously I'm still at fault though. I have found the line that seems to trigger the error. Here's the relevant code of the UIViewController subclass that is creating the UIView and gradient:

```
def loadView

    button1 = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRect.make(x:0, y:55, width:100, height:40))
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer.layer
    gradientLayer.colors = NSArray.arrayWithObjects(UIColor.redColor.CGColor, UIColor.greenColor.CGColor, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor, nil)
```

While more code comes later, I have found that its the `gradientLayer.colors` line that causes the error. If I comment out that line and everything after it in `loadView`, the error doesn't occur. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: There's no error above the "rake aborted" line? Where is `CGRect.make` coming from (for me, I get a NoMethodError when I try to use it) -- have you tried just a simple `CGRectMake(0, 55, 100, 40)` instead? Are you using any 3rd party libraries with this?

Comment: Try this: `gradientLayer.colors = [ UIColor.redColor.CGColor, UIColor.greenColor.CGColor, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor ]`

Comment: @JamonHolmgren - That was it! And of course a much nicer way to create an array. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: @DylanMarkow - I'm using the geomotion gem, which provides CGRect.make

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had trouble creating arrays using NSArray before. Try this:

```
def loadView
  button1 = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRect.make(x:0, y:55, width:100, height:40))
  gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer.layer
  gradientLayer.colors = [ UIColor.redColor.CGColor, UIColor.greenColor.CGColor, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor ]
  # ...
end
```